Finding inputs for equal outputs in monotonically decreasing functions
I have $n$ functions, $f_1,\dots,f_n$. Across these, I want to allocate a known amount $I$ so that $i_1 + i_2 + \dots + i_n = I$ and $f_1(i_1) ≈ f_2(i_2) ≈ \dots ≈ f_n(i_n)$ (equal up to a certain precision). The only information available about the functions is that they are monotonically decreasing.
Which methods are available to find $i_1, i_2, \dots, i_n$?

Can you clarify what "equal up to a certain precision" means?  Is this relative error or absolute error?  Do you require approximate equality between every pair, or only consecutive pairs?

What is the domain for $i_1,\dots,i_n$?  Are they required to be non-negative integers?  Arbitrary integers?  Something else?

How are the functions specified?  As a truth table?  What is the best algorithm you know for this problem?  What is the context where you encountered it or the motivation?

Do the functions evaluate to almost equal values in pair-wise fashion or just in the specified order? Suppose you ensure $|f_k(i_k) - f_{k+1}(i_{k+1})| \le \epsilon$ then $f_1(i_1)$ can be equal to $f_n(i_n) + n\epsilon$.

You can do it in $O(n \log(1/\delta) \log(|I|))$ where $\delta$ is your desired precision and $|I|$ is the size of the domain of $I$ if discretized.
Suppose you arbitrarily choose $i_1 = x$. Then you compute $f_1(i_1)$ and from that you can compute $i_k$ for all $2 \leq k \leq n$ by using a binary search to find $|f_k(i_k) - x| \leq \delta$ for each $i_k$, which will take $\log(1/\delta)$ iterations as $f$ is monotonically decreasing.
Now, after that process is complete (which takes $O(n \log (1/\delta)$ iterations), you get a final $I$ value. If it is too high, you lower $x$, if it is too high you raise $x$ - again you do a binary search on the domain of $I$, which takes $\log(I)$ iterations of the above procedure to find a solution.

The above assumes $i_k$ is real. If it is an integer you'll have to raise your acceptable $\delta$ to whatever lets you always find a valid solution. If that isn't acceptable then the above algorithm doesn't work (and the problem is likely NP-hard in that scenario).
